# fstab ipv6 mounting nfs share on more than one Interface

Tags: fstab

Can I use multiple interfaces in fstab i.e. %wlp2s0 and %eth0.
Is there any wildcards I can use with %.
I am currently running on a laptop and I am using:

[fe80::a:b:c:d%wlp2s0]:/mnt/usbDisk/nfs-share /mnt/storage nfs defaults 0 0

What I would like is that the mount would be swapped to eth0 when a cable is plugged in.
Thanks

Comment: you can't do this with link layer addresses (which *do* require specifying the interface). You'd need a site local, global or ULA address, then everything else would be up to routing settings (not to fstab).

Comment: OK. Thanks for that I dig  a bit deeper.

Comment: Sorted it out using a ULA address

Comment: It would be nice if you posted an answer to your own question explaining what you did to solve the problem.